# Data from web - DataSource.Error - unable to retrieve contents of page

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to get a table from a webpage, but I cannot seem to get PowerBI to correctly load that page.

The url is https://www.argentorshop.be/verkoop-uw-edelmetaal-aan-argentorshop/verkoop-uw-goudstaven-en-of-gouden-munten-aan-argentor/

The table I'm trying to import is the `GOLD KOERSEN` table, highlighted in yellow in this screenshot.
[image: GOLD KOERSEN table]

However, after entering the url, I get
[image: Connecting]

Followed by `DataSource.Error`
`We were unable to retrieve the contents of the web page.`
[image: DataSource.Error]

I already tried adding `HTTP request headers` and `Command timeout` but nothing seems to work.
[image: From Web - advanced]

I also tried to first use a different (working) webpage, and modify the url in the `Source` step

```
Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp")
```

changed to

```
Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.argentorshop.be/verkoop-uw-edelmetaal-aan-argentorshop/verkoop-uw-goudstaven-en-of-gouden-munten-aan-argentor/")
```

but it yields the same error.

Also, trying to wait for a specific `Selector` in the `options` of [Web.BrowserContents(url,options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-browsercontents) by using `[WaitFor = [Selector = "#verkopen > div.bootstrap-table"]]` doesn't do the trick.

Does anyone know of a way to correctly import that table in PowerBI?

Comment: There is some error with your source URL. When I try to use it I get a 404 page not found. I suspect that's a similar issue to what you're experiencing in PBI

Comment: You mean you're getting a 404 when accessing that page in a browser? If so, which browser are you using? The url loads fine on my side in a Chrome browser, evidenced by the screenshot I was able to take from it.

Comment: Chrome too. I'm in the US, whereas it seems you're in or near NL. I noticed that my browser added /en/ to the URL while your screenshot has /nl/ . The URL you provided has neither. I wasn't even able to manually change it to /nl/. Perhaps the automatic language conversions is causing a 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
let
    Source = Web.Contents(
    "http://www.argentorshop.be/nl/graphql",
    [
        Headers=[
            #"Method"="POST",
            #"Content-Type"="application/json"
        ],
        Content=Text.ToBinary("{""query"": ""{sellMetalsGrid (metals: [GOLD]){products {entity_id,name,purchasing_price,buying_premium,spread_percentage,spread_currency,selling_premium,price,image,short_description,product_type,fine_metal_content,metal,url,stock_status}}}""}")
    ]
    ),
    #"JSON" = Json.Document(Source),
    data = JSON[data],
    sellMetalsGrid = data[sellMetalsGrid],
    products = sellMetalsGrid[products],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(products, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"entity_id", "name", "purchasing_price", "buying_premium", "spread_percentage", "spread_currency", "selling_premium", "price", "image", "short_description", "product_type", "fine_metal_content", "metal", "url", "stock_status"}, {"Column1.entity_id", "Column1.name", "Column1.purchasing_price", "Column1.buying_premium", "Column1.spread_percentage", "Column1.spread_currency", "Column1.selling_premium", "Column1.price", "Column1.image", "Column1.short_description", "Column1.product_type", "Column1.fine_metal_content", "Column1.metal", "Column1.url", "Column1.stock_status"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Thank you! I'm really curious now, how you figured out that this was the way to get the data...

Comment: It wasn't easy lol. I checked how the table was being generated using the network tab in the developer tools in Chrome and Firefox. It is dynamically created via AJAX with a call to the graphql endpoint and so I found it and copied the parameters before getting them in the right format for Power Query.

Comment: That's genius! I also looked at the networking tab, but didn't see that. I'm not familiar with AJAX / graphql. Thanks again for your efforts; much appreciated. Learning something new everyday :)